# SharePoint 2013: How can the setting "Show and Hide Ribbon" be enabled for every user independet of permission?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon, site-settings

and thanks in advance for your help.

**I have the following requirement:**

Every user has the possibility to view a pages history.
The ribbon shouldn't be showing all the time, but the users should be able to show it whenever they want to.

**My problem is:**

The setting "Show and Hide Ribbon" is enabled in the site settings, but not every user gets the option to actually show it. If the setting is turned on, the ribbon is hidden on default for every user in the farm. But only users with edit permissions get the option in the gear menu to show/hide the ribbon.

Is there a possibility to configure the setting so that every user can show the ribbon?

Answer (score -1):

Visitors can’t access ribbon on publishing pages in SharePoint 2013 for your reference:

https://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/05/10/visitors-cant-access-ribbon-for-publishing-pages-in-sharepoint-2013/